# Submitting multiple instances of data in ONE post request in Mongo

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, post

I have this module I'm working on, its a post form that takes data for an expense (name, date, amount, an image, and description). I've figured out how to get the post data into mongo for ONE row of data, but I want a user to be able to submit multiple rows (i.e multiple expenses). Unfortunately, when I try to submit the form with multiple instances of this data, I get an error!

> ERROR: Expense validation failed: date: Cast to Date failed for value "[ '2018-07-01', '2018-07-09' ]" at path "date"

Any thoughts on how to correctly submit multiple rows of the aforementioned data?

INFO:

1. I'm using express for the server
2. MongoDB for database

ExpenseForm.js --> (using pug template engine)

```
button#submitExpense(type='submit' form='addExpenseForm').btn Submit 
        // ADD EXPENSE FORM
        form#addExpenseForm(method='POST' action='/expenses').row
          div.col-md-12.add-expense-row-wrapper
            div#expenseRow.row.form-group
              input.form-control.col-md-2(type='text' name='name' placeholder='Enter Name*')
              input.form-control.col-md-2(type='date' name='date')
              input.form-control.col-md-2(type='number' name='amount' placeholder='Enter Amount*')
              input.form-control.col-md-2(type='text' name='description' placeholder='Description*')
              input.col-md-3(type='file' name='file' id='files' placeholder='Upload receipt' multiple)
              button#deleteExpenseRow.col-md-1.btn.delete-expense-row(type='button' )
                i.fas.fa-trash-alt
        div.row.add-expense-button-wrapper 
          button#addExpenseRow.btn(type='button')
            i.far.fa-plus-square
```

Also forgot my Schema

expense.js -->

```
const ExpenseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  employee: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    validate: {
      validator: Number.isInteger,
      message: '{VALUE} is not an integer value'
    }
  },
  description: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  file: {
    type: Buffer,
    required: true
  }
});

var Expense = mongoose.model('Expense', ExpenseSchema);
module.exports = Expense;
```

AND THE POST ROUTE
index.js -->

```
// POST /expenses
router.post('/expenses', function(req, res, next) {
  // Expense.getExpenses({
  //   name: req.body.name,
  //   date: req.body.date,
  //   amount: req.body.amount,
  //   description: req.body.description,
  //   file: req.body.file
  // }, 10, function(err, post) {
  //   if (err) {
  //     return next(err);
  //   }
  //   console.log(req.body);
  //   res.json(post);
  // });


  // create object with form input
  var expenseData = {
    employee: req.body.name,
    date: req.body.date,
    amount: req.body.amount,
    description: req.body.description,
    file: req.body.file
  };

  // store data from from into mongo
  Expense.create(expenseData, function(error) {
    if (error) {
      return next (error);
    } else {
      console.log(expenseData);
      return res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Add your express route's request handler and Mongoose(if you're using) or mongodb schema.

Comment: In your express action you need to check the shape of the data received. Use `Array.isArray(mightBeAnArray)`

Comment: `Cast to Date failed for value "[ '2018-07-01', '2018-07-09' ]".`
`date` is coming as an array, may be you are sending `date` multiple times. Check your Form again.

Answer (score 0):

So, data will come as array. `name` will contain array of all names and so on. You can iterate over all and save in database and then return after saving last item.

```
var employee = req.body.name;
var date = req.body.date;
var amount = req.body.amount;
var description = req.body.description;
var file = req.body.file;

var expenseData = {};

employee.forEach(function(element, index, array) {
    expenseData = {
        employee: employee[index],
        date: date[index],
        amount: amount[index],
        description: description[index],
        file: file[index]
    };
    Expense.create(expenseData, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            return next(error);
        } else {
            if (index === employee.length - 1) {
                return res.redirect('/dashboard');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked beautifully and was such a simple fix. Thank you so much! I am now noticing, however, that any value saved over 1 digit (such as 500) is being saved with only the first digit of said number. Im assuming its an issue with the schema setup. Since we are on the topic, would happen to have a clue as to why this may be? Thanks again!

Comment: I found this once while testing my code that sending multiple parameters with same name appends in an array. Then I saw your error code again in which date was going as an array and read your question again that you are sending multiple instances of data and I guessed it right and solved it for you.

Comment: Checkout this [link](https://blog.karmacomputing.co.uk/duplicate-parameters-in-angular-http/) and related links of that link.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are as follows:

1. You need indeed to collect your data in an array - something that will look like this: expenseArr = [{row1Data}, {row2Data}, ...].
2. Inside your post route you need to import your expenses model - something that will look like this: const expenses = require('thePathAndNameOfYourSchemaExportFile')
3. Call expenses.insertMany(expenseArr) method inside your post route and mongoose will do what's necessary. In this last step, don't forget that you need to wait for the insertMany to complete (recommended that you have a callback in case something goes wrong).